# Animation on Page load only

Tags: javascript, css

I have a home page with an animated title that slides across the screen. I want it to only do this when they first load the page. However, every time you go back to the home page it does it again. Is there anyway to get the animation to only play once and then shut off even if they go back to the home screen?

**Edit:** I have added a `display:none` to the element that had the animation. I then added this javascript but nothing happened.

```
// function viewWebsite {
if (sessionStorage.viewWebsite) {
  sessionStorage.viewWebsite = Number(sessionStorage.viewWebsite) + 1;
} 
else {
  sessionStorage.viewWebsite = 1;
}
if (sessionStorage.viewWebsite < 2) {
  title.style.removeProperty('display');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the home page is a full page reload, so both, plain old pre-HTML5 JavaScript and CSS are unable to discriminate whether it's the first or second visit.

So you have to save it somewhere more persistent.

sessionStorage, built-in in every modern browser is great for that.

So, here are the steps:
You add an additional class to the to-be-animated, that forbids animation. Let's name it `animation-disabled`.
So, upon page load, you check via JavaScript your sessionStorage, whether it contains the key `alreadyVisited`. If it has this flag, do nothing. If it does not have that key, add it to the sessionStorage and remove the CSS class `animation-disabled` from your HTML elements.

Maybe you ask youself, why I chose the don't-animate-by-default approach instead of starting the animation by default and shutting it down after JS has been loaded: It may be, that JS is loaded after the CSS (in fact, it would be best practise to do so) and that would result in a flickering of the animation:

The CSS is loaded, the browser starts animating, then the loading and executing of JavaScript begins: Since it happens also in one thread, chances are, that the animation is not really 60fps. In addition, if JavaScript stops, rather than starts the animation, chances are, that JavaScript has to stop an already-running animation, and that might look really ugly.

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/manono/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank-you. I have tried this out but I don't think I have done it correctly. I put in an edit to show you what I have done.

Comment: I would be glad, if you could "accept" my answer here at Stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

On first visit, show the animation, and store a value in the sever side session variable:

```
<?php $_SESSION['seenSlideshow'] = true; ?>
```

Then test your session variable in order to determine whether or not it is a "First view" of the page.

Your slideshow is most likely JavaScript based, so you may have to echo out the PHP variable to JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seenSlideshow = <?php echo $_SESSION['seenSlideshow'];?>;
</script>
```

Then use that variable to instantiate the slideshow with or without the animation.